# Upper Riemann sum of a branchwise-defined function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Is the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \cos x, & x \in \Bbb Q \\ \sin x, & x \notin \Bbb Q \end{cases}$ Riemann integrable over $[0, \frac \pi 4]$?

Here how do we calculate the upper Riemann uum, $U(P,f)$, after dividing the partition into $n$ equal intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the interval $[0,\pi/4]$ we have $\cos x\ge\sin x$, with equality only on $\pi/4$. Moreover, $\cos x$ is decreasing on that interval. If $P=\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N\}$ is a partition of $[0,\pi/4]$, we deduce that
$$
\sup_{x_{i}\le x\le x_{i+1}}f(x)=\cos x_{i}
$$
and
$$
U(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\cos x_{i}.
$$
If the partition is into $N$ equal intervals, then
$$
U(P,f)=\frac1N\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\cos \frac{\pi\,i}{4\,N}.
$$

Comment: Yes , I understand cosx is decreasing but at xi the cos term contains an irrational number( πi/4N) right? But as per function description it is cosx only when x is a rational number. That is confusing me.

Comment: The rational and the irrationals are dense. By continuity,$$\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]\cap\mathbb Q}\cos x=\cos x_i.$$

Comment: I don't understand, my question is at xi contains a pi term which makes it irrational, so how the function is cos there, as per definition of f(x) it is cosx only when x is rational??

Comment: To compute the upper sum you use $\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(x)$, not $f(x_i)$. Since $\cos x\ge\sin x$, this is equal to $\sup_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]\cap\mathbb Q}\cos x$. Since the rationals are dense in $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, the sup is equal to $\cos x_i$.

Comment: ok. Now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rational numbers and Irrational numbers are dense everyhere, so we can find an x such that value of sin(x) is close to cos(xi). Hence the supremum is taken so. Hope it is clear.

Comment: How can $\sin(x)$ be close to $\cos(x_i)$ on $[0,\pi/4]$?